# Change <span> text on document load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html

I'm working on a WordPress site that uses a dynamically generated menu system which I can't modify becauase of future updates, but what I'd like to do is be able to change the style of the text within one `<span>` in that menu with jQuery on document ready. The span is nested as an `<li>` item, and I don't if that makes a difference. (And I don't see WordPress making a difference, either.) There are other `<span>'s` and I don't want them to change, so I need to match the specific text within the `<span>` I want to change.

So how could I change this `<span>We are here to help.</span>`

to this

`<span style="color:#123456;">We are here to help.</span>`

on  `$(document).ready` ?

The full html is

`<ul id="nav"><li class="li_item"><a class="navlink" href="http://www.mysite.org/contact-us/"><strong>Contact Us</strong><span>We are here to help.</span></a></li></ul>`

**Update:** This works; need to wrap the function in an alias for no conflicts:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#nav li span:contains('We are here to help.')")
.css("color", "#f8481c"); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (assumes `nav` is the id of the `ul` for your menu system):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li span:contains('Text text text')")
      .css("color", "#123456"); 
});
```

For your example [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2MUM/) works:

Comment: Hmmm; looks good but doesn't want to work for me. I added the full html above; does it matter if the #nav is a ul? Thanks...

Comment: There was a syntax error (missing semi-colon at end) that I've amended.

Comment: Flustrating. jQuery is loading fine (from Google, actually). But no luck and an error: "Result of expression '$' [undefined] is not a function" Could this be getting stomped on by something else? But jsFiddle is very cool, will use that in the future.

Comment: Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`. Alternatively you have Prototype or something similar loading first and killing jQuery.

Comment: Does Firebug show jQuery as loaded? Does your page validate (or at least "kinda validate") ?

Comment: Firebug shows jQuery loading, and I disabled some other jQuery scripts. No Prototype. Have a bunch of missing alt tags, etc, but no major validation errors. There is an existing problem with a jQuery slider not working, so they might be related. Site is demon-slayer.org Have to crash now, but thanks for your help and I will be back at this tomorrow.

Comment: Wordpress runs jQuery in `noconflict` mode which means you can't use `$` you have to use `jQuery`. Replace all instances of `$` with `jQuery` and you should be fine.

Comment: or wrap up with `jQuery(function($) { ... });` instead of the document ready... `jQuery(function)` is an alias for `jQuery(document).ready(function)` and the called function receives jQuery as its first parameter, so you can safely use the `$` inside

Comment: Works! Wrapping in the alias might also work for the other jQuery problems. One more detail: in that type of construct .css("color", "#123456")  how wold you add another rule, i.e. font size? Thanks!

Comment: @songdogtech - two ways, one by chaining (e.g. `.css('prop', value').css('prop2', value2')`), the second (probably better way) by using a map: `css({"color":"#123456", "font-size":"12px"})`. See http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

This should work if the :contains isn't working for you.

```
$(function() {
  $('#nav li span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === 'We are here to help.')
      $(this).css('color', '#123456');
  });
});
```

Edit: too many parentheses.

Comment: Actaully, this throws an error: Result of expression '$' [undefined] is not a function?